# Difficult Asymptotic of a Recursive Sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $x_1>1$ and $x_n$ defind by iteration by
$$x_{n+1}=x_n+\frac{1}{\prod_{k=1}^nx_k^{1/n}}$$

> Prove that there exists $C>0$ such that $x_n \sim C\sqrt{n}$.

This exercise seems difficult. Indeed, here is my start.
First, remark that $x_n$ is positive, hence increasing. Therefore, $x_{n+1}-x_n \geqslant \frac{1}{x_n}$, therefore $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2 \geqslant 2$, and we obtain $x_n \geqslant C_1 \sqrt{n}$. Plugging this bound we obtain similarly that $x_n \leqslant C_2\sqrt{n}$ and finally we have $x_n = O(\sqrt{n})$ which is a good start.

Next, we want to prove that $x_n / \sqrt{n}$ indeed converge. In order to do that we juste have to prove that $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2$ is a convergent sequence which I can not prove. This is equivalent to proving that $\frac{x_n}{\prod_{k=1}^nx_k^{1/n}}$ converge.

Here are the details of a further attempt: as we expect $y_n:=x_n/\sqrt{n}$ to converge, we re-write everything in terms of $y_n$ and obtain:
$$y_{n+1}^2-y_n^2=-\frac{y_n^2}{n+1} + \frac{2\sqrt{n}y_n}{(n+1)(n!)^{\frac{1}{2n}}\prod y_k^{1/n}}=\frac{y_n}{n+1} \left(\frac{2\sqrt{n}}{(n!)^{\frac{1}{2n}}\prod y_k^{1/n}}-y_n\right)$$
and now, because of Stirling, we expect that $\lim y_n^2 = \lim y_n \prod y_k^{1/n} = 2\sqrt{e}$, because otherwise, at least if $2\sqrt{e}$ is not a limit value for $y_n^2$, then we have $y_{n+1}^2 -y_n^2 \geqslant \frac{C}{n+1}$ and then $y_n$ is unbounded, which is a contradiction. Therefore, this proves at least that $2\sqrt{e}$ is a limit value of $y_n^2$, and it remains to prove that it is the only one. Assuming $y_{\varphi(n)}^2 \to \ell \neq 2\sqrt{e}$ we deduce that $y_{\varphi(n)+1}^2-y_{\varphi(n)}^2 \geqslant \frac{C}{n}$ but from there I am not able to derive any contradiction ...

Comment: Certainly, you mean $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2$ is a convergent *sequence*.

Comment: You are right, I've edited, thanks.

Comment: What do the bounds you've obtained tell you about $\prod_{k = 1}^{n} x_k$?

Comment: that's the problem @DanielFischer , the bounds are weak. We have $\prod x_k = O(1)^n (n!)^{1/2}$ which is too weak to prove that this is asymptotically equivalent to $x_n$ (modulo a multiplicative constant). 
This just gives $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2=O(1)$ which was known before.

Comment: Numerical evidence seems to suggest that the constant $C$ doesn't depend on $x_1$. That's strange.

Comment: @Professor Vector: if the limit exists it's $\sqrt{2\sqrt{e}}$ because (mostly) Stirling.

Comment: That agrees very well with my numerical results. :-)

Comment: Yes this is exactly the value of the constant, I'll provide the details of the heuristic when I edit the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit**: here is a simplified argument. It relies on the same idea as the original one, but the technique is much easier. The improvement is to replace the asymptotic identity with $x_n^2H_n=\sum{...}+O(n)$ with a simpler argument based on the growth of $x_n$.

Indeed, with the notations of the original argument (we forget the lemmas but consider ourselves at point (**)), if $n=p_m$ is large enough, then for all but $(1-4\sqrt{\epsilon})n$ of the integers $k$ between $1$ and $n$, $x_k > a'\sqrt{k}$. Thus, there is $n > q_m > n-4n\sqrt{\epsilon}$ with $x_{q_m}/\sqrt{q_m} \geq a'$, then $1 \leq \frac{x_n}{x_{q_m}} \leq \frac{\alpha^-+o(1)}{a'}\left(1-4\sqrt{\epsilon}\right)^{1/2}$, and thus $a' \leq \alpha^-(1-4\sqrt{\epsilon})^{-1/2}$. Take $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$ and we find $\alpha^+ \leq \alpha^-$.

---

This is probably not the simplest proof, but I think it works.

Let $G_n = \left(\prod_{k=1}^n{x_k}\right)^{1/n}$. We will use many times that $x_n=\Theta(G_n)=\Theta(n^{1/2})$.

Let $\alpha^{\pm}$ be the liminf ($\alpha^-$) and limsup ($\alpha^+$) of $x_n/\sqrt{n}$, we already know $0 < \alpha^- < \alpha^+ < \infty$.

Let, similarly, $\beta^{\pm}$ be the liminf and limsup of $G_n/\sqrt{n}$. By Stirling, we easily see $\alpha^-e^{-1/2} \leq \beta^- \leq \beta^+ \leq \alpha^+e^{-1/2}$.

But let $t < \beta^-$, then for all large enough $n$, $x_{n+1}-x_n < 1/(t\sqrt{n})$, thus for all large enough $n$, $x_n \leq (2/t)\sqrt{n}$. Thus $\alpha^+ \leq 2/\beta^-$, and similarly $\alpha^- \geq 2/\beta^+$.

As $\beta^- \geq \alpha^-e^{-1/2}$ (resp. $\beta^+ \leq \alpha^+e^{-1/2}$), it follows $\alpha^+ \leq 2e^{1/2}/\alpha^-$ (resp. $\alpha^- \geq 2e^{1/2}/\alpha^+$) and therefore $\alpha^+\alpha^-=2e^{1/2}$.

We have moreover (from the above equations) $\alpha^-\beta^+ \geq 2$, hence $\beta^+ \geq 2/\alpha^-=\alpha^+e^{-1/2}$, and thus (with a similar reasoning) we have $\alpha^- = \beta^-e^{1/2} \leq \beta^+e^{1/2}=\alpha^+$ with $\alpha^-\alpha^+=2\sqrt{e}$.

---

That was the easy part. Now it gets very ugly.

Let $H_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{k^{-1}}$, let $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{1}{x_kG_k}}$.

**Lemma**: $S_n=\frac{H_n}{2}+O(1)$.

*Proof*: $(S_n-S_{n-1})-(H_n-H_{n-1})=\frac{2}{x_nG_n}-\frac{1}{n}=2\ln{\frac{x_{n+1}}{x_n}}-\ln{\frac{n+1}{n}}+O(n^{-2})$, which concludes.

---

**Lemma**: The following estimate holds, for large enough $n$: $$\frac{x_n^2H_n}{2}=\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{H_kx_k}{G_k}}+O(n). (*)$$

*Proof*: $$0.5x_n^2=0.5\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{x_{k+1}^2-x_k^2}+O(1)=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{x_k^2\frac{1}{G_kx_k}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{G_k^{-2}}+O(1).$$
Thus $$0.5x_n^2 = O(\ln{n})+\sum_{k=1}^n{x_k^2(S_k-S_{k-1})}=O(\ln{n})+\sum_{k=1}^n{x_k^2S_k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{x_{k+1}^2S_k},$$ thus $0.5x_n^2=O(\ln{n})-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(x_{k+1}^2-x_k^2)S_k}+ x_n^2S_n.$

Therefore $O(n)=x_n^2\frac{H_n}{2}+O(x_n^2)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{2x_k}{G_k}\frac{H_k}{2}}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{\frac{H_k}{2G_k^2}}+\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{(S_k-0.5H_k)(x_{k+1}^2-x_k^2)},$ and by the first lemma, our estimates on $G,x$ and the usual $H_n \sim \ln{n}$, we find the result (adding the term in $n$ has no issue).

---

The liminf on average of $x_n/G_n$ is the liminf of $x_n^2/2n$ so is $(\alpha^-)^2/2$; but its liminf is above $\alpha^-/\beta^+=(\alpha^-)^2/2$, so the liminf of $x_n/G_n$ is $\alpha^-/\beta^+$ and thus there is a sequence $p_n$ with $x_{p_n} \sim \alpha^-\sqrt{p_n}$ and $G_{p_n} \sim \beta^+\sqrt{p_n}$.

Let $y_n$ be the logarithm of $\frac{x_n}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $C_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{y_k}$, so that the limit points of $y_{p_n}$ are between $\gamma^-=\ln{\alpha^-}$ and $\gamma^+=\ln{\alpha^+}$. By Stirling, and the above, $C_n = \ln{\frac{e^{1/2}G_n}{\sqrt{n}}}+o(1)$, so that $y_{p_n} \rightarrow \gamma^-$, $C_{p_n} \rightarrow \gamma^+$.

Let $0.1 > \epsilon > 0$, we claim that for large enough $n$, there are at most $3\sqrt{\epsilon}p_n$ integers $1 \leq k \leq p_n$ such that $y_k \leq \gamma^+-\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

Indeed, let $N \geq 1$ be such that $y_n \leq \gamma^++\epsilon$ for $n \geq N$. For $n$ large enough, $\sqrt{\epsilon}p_n > N$ and $\sum_{k=N+1}^{p_n}{(\gamma^++\epsilon-y_k)} \leq 2(p_n-N)\epsilon$. By Markov inequality, there must be at most $2(p_n-N)\epsilon/(\sqrt{\epsilon}+\epsilon) \leq 2p_n\sqrt{\epsilon}$ integers $k$ with $y_k \leq \gamma^+-\sqrt{\epsilon}$.

But now, consider the equation (*) with $n=p_m$ for a large enough $m$. There is a subset $S$ made with all the integers from $1$ to $n$ except at most $3\sqrt{\epsilon}n$ such that $x_k \geq a'\sqrt{k}$ for $k \in S$, $a'=\alpha^+e^{-\epsilon}$. (**)

Let us take $b' > \beta^+$, then for finitely many $k$, $G_k < b'\sqrt{k}$. So for $n=p_m$ large enough, there is a set $S$ of at least $n-4\sqrt{\epsilon}n$ integers between $1$ and $n$ such that, for each $k \in S$, $G_k < b'\sqrt{k}$, $x_k > a'\sqrt{k}$.

Note that $\sum_{k \in S}{H_k} \geq (1+o(1))\sum_{1 \leq k \leq (1-4\sqrt{\epsilon})n} {\ln{k}} \geq (1+o(1))n(1-4\sqrt{\epsilon})\ln{n}$.

When considering (*), it follows that for large enough $n=p_m$, $(\alpha^-)^2/2 n\ln{n} \sim x_n^2H_n/2 \geq (1+o(1))a'/b'(1-4\sqrt{\epsilon})n\ln{n}+O(n)$. Therefore, $(\alpha^-)^2/2 \geq a'/b'(1-4\sqrt{\epsilon})$.

Now take $\epsilon \rightarrow 0$, $b' \rightarrow \beta^+$, and thus $(\alpha^-)^2/2 \geq \alpha^+/\beta^+=\sqrt{e}$, thus $(\alpha^-)^2 \geq 2\sqrt{e} = \alpha^-\alpha^+$ and thus $\alpha^-=\alpha^+$.

Comment: Whoa. Nice work.

Comment: @K. defaoite : I've spent a few hours with the problem nagging me. I'm honestly not sure how I even managed to come up with that.

Comment: @Mindlack thank you for the proof. I have to check it however. Maybe it is possible to obtain a simpler proof. I had the feeling to be on the right track (I've edited the initial post to include more attempts). 
How did you came up with such ideas of computations? (After you say "now it gets very ugly")

Comment: @J. Mayol: I wish I knew for certain. Mostly I tried hard and hard to show some variant of $x_n/\sqrt{n}$ to be convergent, or $x_n/G_n$ was enough... but to no avail. But I found a somewhat peculiar situation if there wasn't a limit, a subsequence of $n$ where $x_n$ was "small" but $G_n$ "large". Then it was the matter of finding the right estimate. I tried the Abel summation a bit at random, even though I was aware that $1/x_kG_k$ was an important quantity with well-understood partial sums, as it controlled the growth rate of $x_k$. And then I realized it worked.

Comment: @J.Mayol: indeed, there is a simpler argument with less "weird" calculations. I added it as an edit.

Comment: Looking from way above, this reminds me of the elementary proof of the prime number theorem.

Comment: @marty cohen: I don't know what proof you are taking about -- could you please elaborate?

Comment: Not the details but the forms of the formulas. Here's the original proof:
https://www.math.lsu.edu/~mahlburg/teaching/handouts/2014-7230/Selberg-ElemPNT1949.pdf

Comment: @Mindlack thank you for your explanations. Could you explain what is the meaning of "The liminf on average of $x_n/G_n$" ?

Comment: I meant the liminf of the sequence $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n{\frac{x_k}{G_k}}$.

Comment: I am still wondering if we can turn my attempt of proof into a real proof, like for example exploiting $x_{n+1}^2-x_n^2 =\frac{2x_n}{G_n} + o(1)$ and playing with limsup, liminf to derive $\alpha^+=\alpha_-$

Comment: I think not, because I’ve spent a long while trying to do just that – but I may be wrong. The best result I was able to get is the series of properties of the $\alpha^{\pm}$, $\beta^{\pm}$.

Comment: But starting assuming you have a sequence $p_n$ such that $y_{p_{n}+1}^2-y_{p_n}^2 \geqslant \frac{C}{n}$, isn't it possible to derive that $y_{p_n}^2$ is unbounded ?

Comment: I can’t see why the differences $y_{q+1}^2-y_q^2$, $p_n < q < p_{n+1}$, couldn’t counter the increase in $y_{p_n+1}^2-y_{p_n}^2$.

Comment: @Mindlack yes that is exactly the problem I encountered. Anyway, I am reading your proof, and still have difficulty to read some parts: in the paragraph where you prove that $y_k \geq \gamma^+  - \sqrt{\epsilon}$ for most values of $k$, I do not follow you. There is misprints I guess, could you edit?

Comment: I think I corrected the only one. The idea is as follows – take $z_1,\ldots,z_p$ nonnegative real numbers with their sum $S$. Then there must be at most $S/B$ elements greater than $B$. Now take $p=p_n-N$, $z_i=\gamma^++\epsilon-y_{i+N}$, $B=\epsilon+\sqrt{\epsilon}$, $S \leq 2p\epsilon$.